# How can you get the area of a region from an image?

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, programming, function-construction

Suppose we have a square of side "L" m,

[image]

How can I calculate the hatched area, if the corners of the square are centers of circles.

It can be generalized to any region?

edit:
This is the result I get, as I remove the "i" in response Rahul

```
ConditionalExpression[
 1/64 l^2 (-16 Sqrt[7] + 5 Sqrt[2 (16 - 5 Sqrt[7])] + Sqrt[
    14 (16 - 5 Sqrt[7])] - 5 Sqrt[2 (16 + 5 Sqrt[7])] + Sqrt[
    14 (16 + 5 Sqrt[7])] + 32 ArcCot[Sqrt[7]] - 
    32 ArcSin[5/8 - Sqrt[7]/8] + 32 ArcSin[1/8 (5 + Sqrt[7])] + 
    64 I Log[I Sqrt[13 - Sqrt[7]] + Sqrt[3 + Sqrt[7]]] - 
    64 I Log[Sqrt[3 - Sqrt[7]] + I Sqrt[13 + Sqrt[7]]]), l > 0]
```

Comment: `Area[RegionIntersection[Disk[{l, 0}, l], Disk[{0, l}, l], Disk[{l/2, l/2}, l/2]]]`

Comment: @Rahul Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: Rahul Thank you, could you comment your code and modify something out imaginary parts

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Because I wasn't sure whether I was answering the intended question. Going by the title it's conceivable the OP wants to count the area of the shaded region in the actual raster image rather than in the geometric shape it depicts. Fernando: Can you clarify? Also, what do you mean by "modify something out imaginary parts"?

Comment: I need you to tell me the line of code you put further up the issue put the result gives me, this goes with "i"

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I was quite surprised that Mathematica finds an analytical solution when you just enter the problem in naively:

```
Area[RegionIntersection[Disk[{l, 0}, l], Disk[{0, l}, l], Disk[{l/2, l/2}, l/2]]]
```

On Mathematica 10.1 I don't get the expression with complex terms that Fernando got above, I get the purely real

```
ConditionalExpression[-(1/4)
    l^2 (Sqrt[7] - 2 ArcCot[Sqrt[7]] + 
    4 ArcCot[3/Sqrt[31 + 8 Sqrt[7]]] - 4 ArcTan[4 + Sqrt[7]] - 
    4 ArcTan[1/8 (5 + Sqrt[7] - Sqrt[48 - 6 Sqrt[7]])] - 
    2 ArcTan[1/6 (-12 + 3 Sqrt[7] + Sqrt[31 + 8 Sqrt[7]])] + 
    2 ArcTan[1/48 (9 + 9 Sqrt[7] - Sqrt[1704 + 642 Sqrt[7]])]), l > 0]
```

However, one can fix Fernando's result by applying `FullSimplify` on it, giving the much nicer

```
ConditionalExpression[
 1/4 l^2 (-Sqrt[7] + \[Pi] + ArcTan[(1541 Sqrt[7])/393]), l > 0]
```

i.e.
$$\frac14 \left(\pi +\tan^{-1}\frac{1541 \sqrt{7}}{393}-\sqrt{7}\right)l^2.$$
The two expressions seem to be equal to machine precision, but I can't get Mathematica to verify that they are identical.